# Порядок вызова событий поменятлся?

Tags: javascript, события, dom

Помню, что при наличии нескольких обработчиков событий на элементе в том случае, когда он является целевым (т. е. фаза 2 - targeting), обработчики вызывались подряд в порядке добавления независимо от того, на какую фазу они подписаны (capturing или bubbling).

Но сейчас при запуске вот такого кода и нажатии на кнопку

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button')

btn.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(e.eventPhase, 'Bubbling 1'))
btn.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(e.eventPhase, 'Capturing 1'), true)
btn.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(e.eventPhase, 'Bubbling 2'))
btn.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(e.eventPhase, 'Capturing 2'), true)
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Chrome 93.0.4577.63 выводит

```
2 Capturing 1
2 Capturing 2
2 Bubbling 1
2 Bubbling 2
```

В то время, как Firefox 92.0 показывает

```
2 Bubbling 1
2 Capturing 1
2 Bubbling 2
2 Capturing 2
```

Кто из них прав и почему в Хроме поменялось поведение с тех пор, как я проверял в прошлый раз? Неужели поменяли спецификацию?

PS: Но вообще, новый вариант кажется гораздо более логичным - меня раньше удивляло, что было сделано наоборот.

Comment: проверил несколько браузеров, только в FF отличается поведение и в порядке добавления выполняются. Вероятно остальные просто убрали TARGET PHASE у события, и в этом случае все согласно спеке - сначала те, которые для фазы capture, потом те которые для bubble

Comment: Ну и [судя по спеке](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke) - должны выполнятся в том, порядке в каком они в списке лежат. Но тут вопрос - как их добавляет addEventListener еще

Answer (score 1):

В спецификации (пункт 1.2.1) написано, что порядок выполнение одних обработчиков относительно других никак не регулируется спецификацией.

> Although all EventListeners on the EventTarget are guaranteed to be
> triggered by any event which is received by that EventTarget, no
> specification is made as to the order in which they will receive the
> event with regards to the other EventListeners on the EventTarget.

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/#events-Events-flow

Comment: Так 2 устарела уже. Надо хотя бы 3 смотреть. Вот [тут сказано](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#candidate-event-listeners): _"The list of all event listeners that have been registered on the target object in their order of registration."_

Comment: Согласен, в 3 порядок уже определен. Но даже [самая последняя редакция level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/) пока еще на стадии черновика (Draft). Разработчики браузеров вроде как ориентируются на 2.

Comment: А нет, я ошибаюсь. Level 2 уже почти год не актуален(superseded 3 November 2020). Возможно это изменение поведения хрома связано именно с переходом на level 3.